# Where do I find backed up pictures?

Tags: backup, pictures

I was using a Lumia 1020 which I lost some time ago. Now I want to retrieve the pictures I had taken on it. I've been looking through the Windows Phone website for the past hour trying to find the pictures but to no avail. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

If you turned on automatic camera backup, they would be accessible at https://onedrive.live.com/ in the folder Pictures, Camera Roll